# I want to get latest posts on WordPress to below special HTML

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, posts

I want to get the latest posts on WordPress to below HTML. Can anyone tell me how to code? Thanks!

```html
<div class="cols">
    <div class="col1">
        <ul class="colList">
            <li>post title 1</li>
            <li>post title 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <ul class="colList">
            <li>post title 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rowList">
            <li>post title 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        <ul class="colList">
            <li>post title 5</li>
            <li>post title 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to include them inside the loop https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/ and then use the appropriate variable like `$the_title()`.

Comment: It sounds like more context is required to answer this question

Comment: Please try posting what you have already attempted and what your exact issue is. While we are more than happy to help, StackOverflow is not a project completion site.